# How to have two (or more) instances of a template typename class use the same function

Tags: c++, templates, instances, typename

I'm wondering if it is possible to have a class which uses a `template<typename T>` with functions which the 'typename T' uses by default. I'll give examples:

Header:

```
includes all here
extern template class Object<rectangleBase>
extern template class Object(circleBase>

struct rectangleBase
{
    int width, height;
    int posX, posY;
};

struct circleBase
{
    int radius;
    int posX, posY;
};

template<typename T>
class Object {
public:
    Object();
    ~Object();

    void movePos(int x, int y);

    void setPos(int x, int y);

    T& returnObject() {
        return object;
    }
private:
    T object;
};
```

Source:

```
includes all here
template class Object<rectangleBase>
template class Object<circleBase>

Object<rectangleBase>::Object() { 
    rectangleBase* newObject;
    newObject = new rectangleBase;
    object = *newObject;
}

Object<circleBase>::Object() {
    circleBase* newObject;
    newObject = new circleBase;
    object = *newObject;
}

void Object::movePos(int x, int y) { //here
    object.posX += x;
    object.posY += y;
}

void Object::setPos(int x, int y) { //here
    object.posX = x;
    object.posY = y;
}
```

With the functions setPos and movePos, is it possible that both `<rectangleBase>` and `<circleBase>` can use the same function instead of me having to write the same code out twice because they would use the exact same code, I have show where the functions are in the code.

If this is not possible is there an alternative?

Comment: Why are you explicitly specializing your class with the exact same behaviour ?

Comment: Sorry I don't follow you @Quentin

Comment: I don't understand the question: you are implementing `movePos` and `setPos` only once. What is really concerning about your code is that you are leaking memory: when you call `new circleBase` and `new rectangleBase` you never deallocate that memory. Moreover, you don't really need to explicitly call `new` because if your `T` has a default constructor (or if you write a specialized version of `Object<T>()`), `object` will always be initialize with an empty object (right now you are also making a copy and assigning it to `object`).

Comment: You're specializing the constructor, even though its code is exactly the same apart from the template parameter. Why ? If you just use the base template, all of its functions will just "share" the same code indeed.

Comment: Should that be `Object::setPos()`?

Comment: In the actual program I do deallocate `circleBase` and `rectangleBase` but thank you for pointing out that I don't need to use `new`. Also I only implement `movePos` and `setPos` once because I was asking if it was possible for different typenames to use the exactly same function because they would use the exact same code, otherwise I would have to go `movePos<circleBase>` and `movePos<rectangleBase>`, the same goes for `setPos`, and yes it should be `Object::setPos` @GiovanniBotta

Comment: Did you try compiling it? It should work. But don't forget implementation of template functions must go in the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the same code for multiple different data types (generic programming in a nutshell) is exactly what templates are for. I think you're over-thinking things. The following is sufficient for your use-case:

```
template<typename T>
class Object {
public:
    Object()
    : object()
    { }

    void movePos(int x, int y) {
        object.posX += x;
        object.posY += y;
    }

    void setPos(int x, int y) {
        object.posX = x;
        object.posY = y;
    }

    T& returnObject() {
        return object;
    }
private:
    T object;
};
```

That is all you need. This will work for any `T` that is default-constructible, and then `movePos` and `setPos` can be called if `T` has those two member variables. You don't need to declare specializations at all. Given the above, the following works fine:

```
Object<rectangleBase> r;
r.setPos(5, 6);

Object<circleBase> c;
c.setPos(10, 20);
s.movePos(10, 10);
```

Comment: Thank you, you were right, I was over-thinking things. The problem is now fixed. Thanks again. @Barry

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can:

```
template <typename T>
void Object<T>::movePos(int x, int y) {
    object.posX += x;
    object.posY += y;
}
```

Even your constructors can use this approach:

```
template <typename T>
Object<T>::Object() {
    // This in fact does nothing really different than the default
    // constructor of object but leaks one instance of T.
    T* newObject;
    newObject = new T;
    object = *newObject;
}
```

Templates usually need the whole implementation in header files but if you are fine with limited types that are accepted, you can explicitely instantiate the classes and then you can have the implementation in the source file:

In the header file (anywhere after the class is defined):

```
extern template class Object<rectangleBase>;
extern template class Object<circleBase>;
```

In the source file (anywhere after the methods are defined):

```
template class Object<rectangleBase>;
template class Object<circleBase>;
```

Any other type than `rectangleBase` or `circleBase` won't work with this setup.

Comment: when putting `extern template class Object<rectangleBase>;` `class` has an error saying `extern template cannot follow explicit instantiation of class "Object<rectangleBase>"` and the same goes for `Object<circleBase>` @StenSoft

Comment: @Jack `extern template class` must be before `template class`. You seem to have somewhat wrong `#include`s in the source file. `template class` need to be after `#include` of the header file or it won't know what to instantiate (`#include`s should usually be before anything else).

Comment: code above have been changed to how I used it, is that correct? If so `class` still gives me the same error @StenSoft

Comment: @Jack `extern template class` needs to be after the class is defined (usually at the end of the header; added to explanation). The same goes for `template class` and the methods.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your problem. You should simply implement your functions, instantiate template and use your objects.

I tried, this, it works. Please, take a look: http://ideone.com/717044

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct rectangleBase
{
    int width, height;
    int posX, posY;
};

struct circleBase
{
    int radius;
    int posX, posY;
};

template<typename T>
class Object {
public:

    Object() { }
    ~Object() { }

    void movePos(int x, int y)
    {
        object.posX += x;
        object.posY += y;
    }

    void setPos(int x, int y)
    {
        object.posX = x;
        object.posY = y;
    }

    T& returnObject() { return object; }

private:
    T object;
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    Object<rectangleBase> a;
    Object<circleBase> b;
    b.setPos(1,2);
    printf("px: %d", b.returnObject().posX);
}
```

If you are interested how many instances of the function compiler would generate,
(ex: the code of your functions is huge), most likely compiler will generate as many instances of similar code as many different instantiations you have. Optimizer may collapse some of them. But if optimizer will do this or not - this is hard to tell.

Approach when you use fields, methods, enums, etc. of the parameters types from the body of the template directly is called using dependent types. Yes, this approach makes it difficult or impossible to instantiate your template with types that do not have this field or member function. Nevertheless this pattern is widely used.

Comment: I have used this code and I get this error 'rectangleBase::rectangleBase(void): attempting to reference a deleted function' @KirillKobelev

Comment: Define (if needed empty) constructor and destructors in your parameter types. It should work.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean? @KirillKobelev

Comment: 'rectangleBase::rectangleBase(void): attempting to reference a deleted function' - this means that your compiler believes that this method is deleted. Read about deleted methods here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor. You need to modify your code so, that this constructor is defined. I do not see your full code. It is hard to tell what is going on exactly.